# React - On change of radiobutton component, update textbox component state

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component, react-state-management, react-state

I have 3 components. Main Component named 'XYZ' which contains 2 other components named 'RadioButton' and 'Textbox'. I need to update state of Textbox component (Setting value to 500) on change of RadioButton component. Below is my code. I am new to React development. Any help would be surely appreciated!

Main Component - XYZ.tsx

```
const XYZ = (props) => {
    let lossCapacityValues = [
        { value: "Average", text: "Average" },
        { value: "Medium", text: "Medium" }
    ];

    const lossCapacityChange = (event) => {
        let ele = $(event.target);
    };

    return (
        <div className="mel-box">
            <RadioButton groupName="radio-loss-type" selectedValue="2" items={lossCapacityValues} onChange={lossCapacityChange} />
            <TextBox value="1000" />
        </div>
    )
};

export default XYZ;
```

Child Component - 1- RadioButton.tsx

```
const RadioButton = (props) => {

    const onChange = (event) => {
        props.onChange && props.onChange(event);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.items.map((i: { "text": string, "value": string }, index: number) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="radiobutton-option-div">
                            <input
                                className="radio-custom"
                                type="radio"
                                name={props.groupName}
                                value={i.value}
                                defaultChecked={i.value === props.selectedValue}
                                onChange={onChange}
                            />
                            <label className="radio-custom-label">
                                <span className="radio-custom-text">{i.text}</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default RadioButton;
```

Child Component - 2- TextBox.tsx

```
const TextBox = (props) => { 
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        value: props.value
    });

    const handleChange = (evt) => {
        setState({ value: evt.target.value });
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="input-text">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={state.value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )

};

export default TextBox;
```

Comment: The most normal way is to use [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to handle state passed via components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), out of the TextBox component into the XZY component.

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9p0v7oqd/)**

In XYZ, put the text state handlers:

```
const XYZ = (props) => {

    const [textState, setTextState] = React.useState({
        value: 1000
    });

    const handleTextChange = (evt) => {
        setTextState({ value: evt.target.value });
    };

    ....
    ....

};
```

Pass them as props:

```
<TextBox value={textState.value} onChange={handleTextChange} />
```

Change your input to use them:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.onChange}
/>
```

In your XYZ you can check the selected radio value and set the text state accordingly.

```
const lossCapacityChange = (event) => {
    //let ele = $(event.target);
    if(event.target.value == 'Average'){
        setTextState({ value: 500 });
    }
};
```

Side note: you should avoid the use of jQuery in React unless there is a good reason for it. React uses a Virtual DOM which can be affected by jQuery use.